# How to transform an accuracy distribution for a violin plot

Tags: data-visualization, boxplot, accuracy

I am trying to find the best way to visualize different distributions of accuracy. Accuracy here is a value in the interval [0,1], 0 meaning not accurate, 1 maximum accuracy.

I have different methods to compare, so I decided to use violin plots.

[image: accuracy violin plots]

Distributions are clustered near 1 but they have also a long tail (the first one is cut at 0.45).

How can I transform the data (e.g. in log-scale), in order to visualize better the differences between these plots? I want to focus in the interval [0.8, 1], but I want also to retain the long tails.

I do not want to use boxplots because in this case I saw that they do not show correctly the distributions (also because the lower quartile is already 1).

I add also the corresponding boxplot.

[image: boxplot]

Thanks

Comment: If the first quartile (the lower quartile) is 1, then at least 75% of the distribution is at 1. In that case, no transformation will separate those values at 1, since they all have the same value - they'll always be transformed to the same thing. One thing you can do is look at the ecdf, perhaps.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: If the **lower** quartile is already 1, then how it is readable from these plots that more than 75% of the values are at the right-hand edge? Either they lie or they are extraordinarily over-smoothed.

Comment: @NickCox I used http://boxplot.tyerslab.com/ .. in fact, it is the first time I use violin plots - I do not exactly what to expect

Comment: Saying you used a particular program (command, function, routine, whatever) is not itself very informative. Did you just accept the defaults? Did you think about tuning choice(s) if any are offered? Regardless of that, smoothing a spiky distribution with a spike at an extreme is a dubious thing to do. What happened to the mass smoothed above 1? Is it reflected or did it disappear? Can you explain what you did?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no relevant options for violin plots in that application, from what I saw. I read your answer, and I agree with you that with such distribution it is not very compelling to use violin plots. The mass above 1, if I understood correctly your questions, simply does not exist, because the accuracy has 1 as maximum value.

Comment: The point is that the actual distribution is all $\le 1$ as you say, but nevertheless any two-sided smoothing technique would push some of that mass above $1$; so what happens to that fraction of the mass? Is it reflected back or ignored? This is a small detail in my view; the larger point to me is that the violin plot, from what you tell us, is not showing the distribution fairly.

Comment: I think the mass above 1 is ignored. But I am not expert enough to tell you if the distribution is shown fairly.. I thought that, because the lower quartile is already 1, the density of the distribution reaches the maximum in 1 and what we can see to compare the four methods is the left tail. But maybe I misunderstood the meaning of the plot.

Comment: I don't think the issue requires much expertise. You are telling us that >75% of the values are 1; I can't see that the violin plots tell us that, except that in 3 out of 4 instances there seems to be a minute fragment of a box. Conversely, the other instance seems to show more of a box. So I have no sense that the violin plots are showing the data faithfully. I've already suggested an alternative visualization. Another would be a quantile plot.

Comment: Ok Nick, I will try your suggestion (I think it can be better visualized with an histogram).. Also, I have added the corresponding boxplot to the question, just in case it can show more insights

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have various takes on this.

1. Don't expect too much from transformation. I read your results as saying that the upper quartile (**not* usually called the first quartile) is 1; hence >25% of the values tie at 1 and you have a spike in the distribution. Any one-to-one transformation will inevitably map a spike to a spike. There's no escape from that. (Also, see #4: I don't view this kind of visualization as a good idea in the presence of a spike, but there is some statistical taste and judgment in that view.) [EDIT: The original was edited to stating that it's the lower quartile that is 1. This intensifies #1 mightily.]
2. Log transformation is definitely inappropriate as it will stretch your tail out further. Its inverse, say exp(), won't help much here as it is too near linear over this narrow range. Some high power, say fourth or higher, should make the distribution a little more symmetric, but can't solve #1.
3. Why do you think you need a transformation? The results are as they are. Thinking you need a transformation often arises from a misconception that (e.g.) data must be nearly normal to do much with them, but that's an exaggeration. If you spell out analyses you plan downstream from this, there should be better advice forthcoming.
4. I don't find the visualizations at all compelling, if only because it's hard to read off the precise differences between the distributions. I would try very fine binning, e.g. intervals of 0.01, and then look at histograms using a log frequency scale. In my view, an honest visualization would show spikes as such, not smooth over them.